# How do I correctly compute this final uniform matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, transformation

Im trying to understand how matrix transformations work in opengl/glsl, and Im wondering how to make a single 4x4 id-matrix that has the potential for every scale/rotation/translation.

So, after all the binding and whatnot, im only uniform/inputting 1 matrix to designate its location/spin.

This idea seems correct to me, but I cant figure out how to make the object move without distorting it. It rotates just fine, and it scales as well.

But idk how to apply the translation to the id matrix, if that makes sense. In any case, this is my relevant code:

```
//update matrix
glUniformMatrix4fv(transform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ident));

//spin according to z
void object::spinz(float a) { ident = glm::rotate(ident, a, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); }
```

this will modify my

```
glm::mat4 ident();//id matrix
```

but when i try giving it translation:

```
void object::translate(float x, float y, float z);
```

the method itself will only distort the object/matrix/result

```
ident +=  glm::vec4(x, y, z, 0);
```

what am I doing wrong? Should I even try to only have 1 uniform input?

**Solution: the idea for translation is just wrong. A correct one would look more like this:** (but the main thing is doing it seperately for each object)

```
glm::mat4 test = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(x, y, z));
finaluniformmatrix *= test;
```

Or basically make a unique translation matrix, that I then multiply with the overall projection*view matrix.

edit: a cheaper translation is:

```
matrix[3][0]=x;matrix[3][1]=y;matrix[3][2]=z; //where xyz are xyz coordinates.
```

ps: why am I getting downvotes for this? This is me finding out (some time ago) that you need a unique identity matrix for rendering seperate objects, and not just the same matrix for everything. (like mixing up projection, view, identity, by adding them for each object)

Comment: You've to multiply the translation matrix with the matrix that scales and rotates, not add a vector to it. Successive transformations are concatenated by multiplication and not addition. [Understand transformations](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/2d-transforms-101-r4212) first before coding these things.

Comment: so ill need a matrix for each of the transformations? hm, that might be it actually

Comment: well, I feel silly now, i wasnt using matrices in my computations, but rather adding vectores (like a fool). thanks man =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a number of individual matrix operations, and multiply them together to turn them in to a single matrix that specifies the entire operation.  Any number of 4x4 matrices can be multiplied and the order IS important.

Also be wary of non uniform scale and rotation, which can sometimes have the effect of "sheering" the object.

You can fairly simply build translation, rotation-x, rotation-y, rotation-z and scale 4x4 matrices and multiply them together to create a single matrix.

http://www.flipcode.com/documents/matrfaq.html#Q11

http://www.flipcode.com/documents/matrfaq.html#Q41

I'm not sure about the code you are using tho - I'd suggest only using 4x4 matrix and multiply operations to begin with and work from there.

Comment: [This](http://www.j3d.org/matrix_faq/matrfaq_latest.html) is the updated version of _The Matrix and Quaternions FAQ_.

Comment: you fixed it by suggesting using more matrices, i feel silly for not realizing earlier, thanks man =)